# Create a table using a variable for it's name in Python 3

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, ubuntu

```
table = "CREATE TABLE " + newTable + "(id int(2),description varchar(20))"
```

(EDIT: now this work)

But this not

```
table = """CREATE TABLE" + newTable + "(
   id int(2),
   description varchar(20))"""
```

Thanks in advance!

this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ...
  raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax..."
```

If you need a extended log of error i need to know how can i copy the log in a file

Comment: what error you you get? Probably syntax error which you should include in your question. You need a space after "TABLE" . Second `"""` example - needs to understand how interpolation works with blockquotes. If in doubt, `print table`

Comment: What's the value of newTable (please show code) and I suggest a space after create table.

Comment: amazing, i only needed to space after create table... it still can't do work with """ but it work with a single line. ill update the ask with the error with multiple lines

Comment: You have too many quotes in the multi table version - and it's really not difficult to print(table) and this is a basic question on how to code in python